# 7-zip: Double click to extract a zip file, then open the extracted folder

Tags: 7zip

I would like to extract and automatically open the extracted folder of a zip file by double-clicking it, using 7-zip (preferably, but not mandatory). Currently on Windows 10.

Currently, there are many known solutions([example](https://superuser.com/a/447791/1703362)) to the half of what I want; that is, extracting a zip file by a double-click. I have tried to manipulate the command line given in the [example](https://superuser.com/a/447791/1703362) as the following:

> `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "%1" -o*`
> modified to
> `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "%1" -o* && start "%1"`

To explain what I exactly want to accomplish in details, when I double-click a zip file, it would extract into a folder with path: `"%currentLocation%\filename"`

Then, I want the extracted folder to be opened on the explorer automatically.